# 404 error on Windows with Slim framework and space in folder name

Tags: php, slim

I'm on Windows. When I use the following URL

```
http://localhost/slim%20framework/public/index.php/test
```

It give me 404 error, but when I use this URL

```
http://localhost/slimFramework/public/index.php/test
```

It works properly.

So, when my folder name is `"slim framework"`, a 404 error occurs but when the folder name is `"slimFramework"`, it's working fine.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I know it's an old thread but i am curious to know how your problem was solved.